# btrfs same inode number

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, inode

I have a btrfs file system, and it all the folders in the top level are inode 256.
This is not good for me, the device id is the same, So I assume these are "virtual inodes numbers", Btrfs has their own mechanism of doing this.

Is it possible to get the real unique physical inode of each directory ?

look what happens:

```
root@ReadyNAS-DEV:/home# find  / -xdev -inum 256
/
/home
/data
/apps
root@ReadyNAS-DEV:/home#
```

Thats not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the three directories `/home`, `/data` and `/apps` are mount points.

When you mount something on `/home`, the inode that is reported for `/home` is the inode of the root directory of the mounted partition, not that of the original `/home` directory. It is therefore not strange that these inodes are the same as those of other partition's root directories.

On my OpenBSD machine (which doesn't use btrfs):

```
$ find / -xdev -inum 2
/
/home
/usr
/var
/tmp
```

I see the same on my Ubuntu VM. This is not a bug.

Another way of saying it:  The `stat` structure returned by the `stat()` system call for the different directories have the same value of `st_ino`, but different values of `st_dev`. See the description of [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) and [`sys/stat.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) in POSIX.

It may be that you misunderstand the `-xdev` option to `find`.  With it, it will not *descend* into those directories that are on other filesystems, but it will still print the directory names if they match the other criteria.